# angularjs double curly braces don't work

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `Angular JS`, when I tried to get and print out some `JSON` data using `$scope` variable, but double curly braces just don't work as i thought it would do.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-08">
    <meta name="author" content="YYQ">
    <meta name="description" content="YYQAngularJS">
    <title>YYQAngularJS</title>
    <script src="Script/angular.js" type="javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
<div> haha {{ p.name }} </div>

<script src="Script/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/index.js" type="javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$(window).on("load",function () {

    var $myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    $myApp.controller('myController',function ($scope) {
        $scope.p =
            {
                "name":"a",
                "id":"1"
            }
    });

});
```

result:

haha {{ p.name }}

Update:

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-08">
        <meta name="author" content="YYQ">
        <meta name="description" content="YYQAngularJS">
        <title>YYQAngularJS</title>
        <script src="Script/angular.js" type="javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myController">
    <div> haha {{ p.name }} </div>

    <script src="Script/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/index.js" type="javascript"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

JS file:

```
var $myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        $myApp.controller('myController',function ($scope) {
            $scope.p =
                {
                    "name":"a",
                    "id":"1"
                }
        });
```

And now i got this error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `$(window).on("load",function () {`
- Change `type="javascript"` to `type="text/javascript"` in all `<script></script>` tags

Angularjs will load it before DOM is loaded

Here is the working code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-08" />
  <meta name="author" content="YYQ" />
  <meta name="description" content="YYQAngularJS" />
  <title>YYQAngularJS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div> haha {{ p.name }} </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

      var $myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      $myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.p = {
          "name": "a",
          "id": "1"
        }
      });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it works, thanks, but if i remove $(window).on("load",function () { } in js file, it still doesn't work, i wonder why.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for the application to fail. Go to the console and check the error you are getting and share it

Comment: oh i have this error here, it says module 'myApp' is not available.

Comment: ok then one thing is confirm. The  scpit file is not loaded in your page. Check script path and then keep the script tag right below the angularjs script tag. If the issue persists share the code. Here is the working plnk link http://plnkr.co/edit/yCG4JwySSeJOpz04Ooqm?p=preview

Comment: got the issure with the code. 
Change `type="javascript"` to `type="text/javascript"` in all `<script></script>` tags

Comment: you are right, i just found the problem as well, i never thought there is difference between type="javascript" and type="text/javascript" thought.

Comment: If the answer solved the problem kindly accept the answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).on('load', () => {})` is causing conflict with your angular app.

```js
var $myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

$myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.p = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Angular App working"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-08">
    <meta name="author" content="YYQ">
    <meta name="description" content="YYQAngularJS">
    <title>YYQAngularJS</title>
    <script src="Script/angular.js" type="javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
<div> haha {{ p.name }} </div>

<script src="Script/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/index.js" type="javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's kinda odd, it works if i just put the js code in html file script tag, but if i put it in separate js file, it doesn't work again. im wondering why is that.

Comment: It depends how are you including the js code in separate file. Can you show us the code?

Comment: i just found the problem, i shouldn't have used the type="javascript" attribute.